# Errors after migrating wordpress site via Akeeba

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

I'm migrating a wordpress website from hostgator to godaddy using Akeeba and throughout the process all seemed fine but after completion I got the following errors. Any help with resolving this issue would be much appreciated. DNS is currently pointing back to the original site for the time being.

Thanks!

Warning: include(/home4/bdr107/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-base.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bdr107/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 65

Comment: It appears you are using a caching plugin that is trying to include a file that doesn't exist. You should try to go into the admin panel for that plugin and try to force a recache of files.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response! I actually figured it out and you're right it was the supercache plugin using a direct file path causing the error. I disabled the plugin via the database and that solved the issue. I was unable to even access the admin dashboard.